# Is there a way to fix android apps not connecting to the network on android 9 but works on android 8

Tags: codenameone

I built a codenameone simple app. On android 8 the app connects fine to the network but on android 9 it can not connect. Is there a way to fix this?

I have tried to connect via https but still did not work.

Comment: Please show us your manifest

Comment: you can try to run in the simulator and clear cache.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121953/usescleartexttraffic-not-permitted/57130188#57130188