# How to solve Connection error while connecting to http via mobile build?

Tags: codenameone

When I build my app and try connecting to my API through (http://ip_address/8080/) am getting this error "There was a networking error in the connection to http://ip_address:8080/". But from my IDE is working perfectly. What could be the problem and can it be sorted out. Kindly help

Answer (score 2):

Android 9 stopped working on HTTP by default, it supports HTTPS only. To enable HTTP, use the build hint:

```
android.xapplication_attr=android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57130188

Also iOS doesn't support HTTP by default. To enable HTTP, use the build hint:

```
ios.plistInject=<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>
```

Reference: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html

Comment: Kindly how do I do it kindly?

Comment: You can set these hints by right clicking the project in the IDE and selecting Codename One → Codename One Settings → Build Hints. The hints use the key=value style of data. More information: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_sending_arguments_to_the_build_server

Comment: So in this case what is our key and value?

Comment: `android.xapplication_attr` is a key, `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` is its value. `ios.plistInject` is a key, `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>` is its value. However simply copy and paste the build hints as I reported them in the answer.

Comment: These are build hints. You need to open the Codename One Settings/Preferences application and go to the build hints section within the app