# How to add cleartextTraffic for Android?

Tags: codenameone

Could you please tell me how to add the:

```
<application 
    . . .
    android:usesCleartextTraffic=["true" | "false"]
    . . .
</application>
```

to the codenameone settings?  My app is to connect an http server on the local network.

Thanks for your help.

Emmanuel

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57130188/756809

Comment: Hello Shai, thanks for your response.  Still, I cannot figure out how to add 
android.xapplication_attr=android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
to codenameone_settings.properties

Answer (score 1):

There we are for the records:

```
codename1.arg.android.xapplication_attr=android\:usesCleartextTraffic\="true"
```