# Codename One front-end with Spring Boot back-end

Tags: spring-boot, codenameone

I have a test Codename One project that includes a Spring boot project as an included module.
[image: my_test_project_layout]

Everything runs fine with the Spring Boot server and cn1 simulator. I tried using the cn1 build server to generate an .apk to test on my smartphone. The app opens ok, but there is a network error in the connection to the target uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a module. It's a separate project. The Spring Boot application runs on the desktop but it can't run in the device and we won't build it into a native application. It can serve as a backed on a server which the device needs to "see" which means you need a web address that's accessible by the device.

If it's on your local machine and you're connected to the local network you need to allow HTTP access (Android requires HTTPS by default) by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121953/usescleartexttraffic-not-permitted).